# Handling multiple x-tags

Tags: javascript, x-tag

***Note:***
This question is based on an old version of Mozilla x-tag.

In my project I'm using [Mozilla x-tag](http://x-tags.org/). I created this tag called x-master. I got two of those tags in my index.html:

```
<div id="page-one" data-role="page">
<x-master id="x-one" data-src="source1"></x-master>
</div>
<div id="page-two" data-role="page">
<x-master id="x-two" data-src="source2"></x-master>
</div>
```

xtag component looks like this:

```
(function(window, document, undefined) {
var jsonurl;

xtag.register('x-master', {
onCreate : function() {
jsonurl = this.getAttribute('data-src');
},
methods : {
getContent : function(){
$.getJSON(jsonurl, function(data){ console.log(jsonurl); };
}
}
})(this, this.document);
```

**My problem:**
When I call the method getContent for id x-one it prints: source2. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this to work is to make an object with the jsonurl. Thanks to [Florian Margaine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022928/handling-multiple-x-tags#answer-14023031) who got me to this right solution.

How to do this:

> ```
> (function(window, document, undefined) { 
> function props() {
>     this.jsonurl; 
> }
>
> xtag.register('x-master', {
>     onCreate : function() {
>        this.props = new props();
>        this.props.jsonurl = this.getAttribute('data-src');
> },
>     methods : {
>         getContent : function(){
>              $.getJSON(this.props.jsonurl, function(data){ console.log(jsonurl); };
>         }
> }
> })(this, this.document);
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I would advise grabbing the latest version of X-Tag - the spec changed as it has moved through later stages of the standardization process, that version is quite old. The API in place now for X-Tag will be compatible with the final spec and can be used now across all major browsers all the way back to IE9: http://x-tags.org/

Here's what your code would look like optimized with X-Tag's built-in features:

```
xtag.register('x-master', {
    accessors: {
        src: {
            attribute: {},
            set: function(src){
                // Using the attribute <--> accessor auto-linkage feature of 
                // X-Tag, both your created lifecycle event and getContent method
                // become unnecessary. If src is present on creation, or changed
                // at any time, your setter is automatically executed. Simply set
                // the src property/attribute and it will do your AJAX call.
                $.getJSON(src, function(){ ... })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: True. Added a note at the start of the question.

Answer (score 2):

In this part:

```
onCreate : function() {
jsonurl = this.getAttribute('data-src');
```

each time a x-master initialized, jsonurl is assign a value from current x-master. That's why you always get the data-src of the last element.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `jsonurl` a property of the object, not a variable shared by all the x-master.

```
var props = function() {
    var jsonurl;

    return { 
        onCreate: function() {
            jsonurl = this.getAttribute('data-src');
        },

        methods: {
            getContent: function() {
                $.getJSON(jsonurl, function(data) {
                    console.log(jsonurl);
                };
            }
        }
    };
};

xtag.register('x-master', props());
```

Comment: I think this might be close to the answer I am looking for. Shouldn't I create a new instance on props?

Comment: @Klaasvaak not really, the `register` function only expects one object.

Comment: @Klaasvaak I edited to use a better solution, simply putting `jsonurl` in a closure.

Comment: Oke, I tryed your answer but it gives me the same problem. jQuery.extend({}, props); instead of just props in the register function gives the same problem aswell.

Comment: Ok, I will try your new answer later on. I will let you know. Thanks for the help.

Comment: jsonurl still has the same value in your new example.

Comment: Thanks for your help you made me get to the right solution. I posted the answer.

Comment: @Klaasvaak glad you got it sorted out!